# React Next.js: getServerProps is not returning array from prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prisma

##### Background

After learning [getServerProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), I tried building a project that returns some data from postgres using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/nextjs#nextjs-tabs), but for some reason, when I try to map the posts array ( See below ), it returns the array as undefined. Enevn I believe I followed syntax rules on the Doc page, no luck so far. I have been stuck for long time and I don't know why and what i did wrong. At least VS code recognize posts as array, but getServerProps function seems it never gets run.Thanks for reading, lemme know your thoughts on this.

##### Summary of my problem

- I don't know why the array (`posts` variable) is undefined when it is recognized inside of the function.
- I don't know why getServerProps seems to be not called

##### Note:

Prisma and postgres are working in this project

### Posts.js

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
function Posts({ posts }) {

return (
  <div>
    <h1 className="text-4xl block text-gray-500 font-bold pt-5 text-center">
      Posts
    </h1>
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>;
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany()

    
    return { props: { posts } }
  }

export default Posts
```

### schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String
}
```

Error I get:

#### Error message

[image: Error Message]

#### Prisma Studio

[image: Prisma studio]

#### File structure

[image: FileStructure]

### After studying the best answer on StackOverflow

[image]

Comment: You might want to include `schema.prisma`... it's hard to tell from what you have.

Comment: @code Thank you for pointing out, there is my `shema.prisma`

Comment: Your code seems correct. Is your `Posts.js` file under `/pages` directory?

Comment: What does your file structure look like? (Only include relevant directories and files.)

Comment: I added image of the file structure. allpost.js is for api route for CreatePast.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `getServerSideProps` outside of `pages` directory. Change your code so that the prisma call is inside your page, and the posts are passed to `Posts` component using props. For example if you are displaying the posts in `pages/index.js`:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany()
    
  return { props: { posts } }
}

function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <Posts posts={posts}/>
  );
}

export default Home
```

Side note: You should not create a `PrismaClient` every time `getServerSideProps` is called. Create a prisma.js file, initialize it there and reuse when you need it:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

let prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient()
} else {
  // Ensure the prisma instance is re-used during hot-reloading
  // Otherwise, a new client will be created on every reload
  globalThis.prisma = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient()
  prisma = globalThis.prisma
}

export default prisma
```